# Android Studio new version APK generation Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, exception

Hello on Android studio version 2.2 when I created an application, and then ran it, android studio would create an apk on the outputs/apk folder. If I were to go into that folder and grab that apk and install it on any device it would work great! Ever since i updated to Android studio 2.3 this is no longer the case. It seems when I run the application and try to grab the apk I get exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
```

However this exception does not appear when I click the build tab and select  build ap. Any ideas why this is happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you pls post the part of your gradle file where you have added the dependency.

Comment: @GradleDroid Sure thing! I have updated my question with the dependencies I am using. Thank you!